# How to convert a string with spaces to list in python

Tags: python

I want to convert a string to a list.

```
fName = input("Enter your First Name: \n")
lName = input("Enter your Last Name: \n")
location = input("Enter your Location: \n")

string = fName + " " + lName + " " + location

print(string)
print("String coverted to list :",string.split())
# Output : String coverted to list : ['name', 'name', 'location']

print("String coverted to list :\n",list(string))
# Output: String coverted to list : ['n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'c', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n' ]
```

Desired Result :

```
#Output : [ namenamelocation]
```

Basically I do not want the list to get separated after spaces and want the term string to be a single index in list.

Comment: `print("String coverted to list :\n", [string])`

Comment: Do ```[string.replace(" ", "")]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# remove spaces and then put into list
[string.replace(" ", "")]
```

To add, if you don't add the spaces at the beginning, you don't need to use `.replace()`, just the brackets `[]`

```
string = [fName + lName + location]
```